# jqgrid - tooltip or title for cell not displaying for 2000 + characters

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, tooltip, cell, title

I am trying to get tooltip or title with 2000 characters for a cell in a table with image. Tried using various things but not able to get any solution. Please help. My code for the column,

```
    {
    name: 'comments',
    index: 'comments',
    width: 80,
    align: 'center',
    resizable: true,
    sortable: false,
    editable: false,
    cellattr: function(rowId, val, rawObject) {
        return 'title="' + val + '"'
    },
    formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
        if (cellvalue.length <= 0) {
            return cellvalue;
        } else {
            var image = "<img src='/images/comment.png' />";
            return image;
        }
    }
},
```

Second code trial,

```
{
    name: 'comments',
    index: 'comments',
    width: 80,
    align: 'center',
    resizable: true,
    sortable: false,
    editable: false,
    formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
        if (cellvalue.length <= 0) {
            return cellvalue;
        } else {
            var image = "<img src='/images/comment.png' title='Comments:\n" + cellvalue + "'/>";
            return image;
        }
    }
},
```

Above code did not display any tooltip when there are 2000 characters.

Also tried,

```
var image = '<figure><img src='/images/comment.png' title='Comments:\n"+cellvalue+"'/></figure>';
```

This is loading the tooltip very slow.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1) I guess it's not good idea to use title 2000 chars long. Browser may truncate it (like Firefox) or it will work slow.

You may try this code:

```
<figure><img src='/images/comment.png' id='img'/></figure>

var x = '1234567890';
var y = '';

for (var j=0;j<200;j++)
y+=x;

var i = document.getElementById('img');
i.title = y;
```

Live demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/hbofay8g/

2) Much better idea is use hover popup. Something like described here
http://creativeindividual.co.uk/2011/02/create-a-pop-up-div-in-jquery/

In this case you have more control over style: color, scrolls, size etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this, but in my jqgrid table this option did not work :(